# how to check if a checkbox is checked, convert tobool fails since its lower case 'false'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am doing:

`convert.toboolean(request.form["mycheckbox"]`

but since the value is 'false', it doesn't seem to cast to boolean.

What should I do?

I don't like checking for `== "false"` and then converting to boolean.

is there a cleaner way?

**Update**

All I am doing is:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(request.Form["somecheckbox"]))
{


}
```

Comment: The return value of `Convert.ToBoolean` is `bool` so you should be able to just test it directly. Can you post some more code?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx, Convert.ToBoolean is NOT case-sensitive.  Apparently your request.form["mycheckbox"] is returning something other than "true" or "false".

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean("false")` gives me `false`, `Convert.ToBoolean("true")` gives me `true`...

Comment: hmm..let me check again, this is confusing to me also as I never ran into this issue b4.

Comment: Split off the `request.Form["somecheckbox"]` to a separate line and double check what it returns.

Comment: I'm using Html.Checkbox helper to generate the checkbox, it is generating a checkbox input field AND a input hidden field???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Html.Checkbox` helper creates a checkbox and a hidden field, both with the name that you provide ("mycheckbox").  The hidden field appears to have the original value of the checkbox (though I could be off on what, exactly, its purpose is).

I would say that if you're getting values manually out of the `Request` collection, you should be creating your controls manually, too, instead of using `Html.Checkbox` and similar helpers, which may add other stuff that the framework knows about but you don't.

The other alternative would be to let the framework bind that value, rather than getting it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool b = request.form["mycheckbox"] != null && request.form["mycheckbox"] == "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToBoolean` is to be used for "0" and "1"

You can also try `Boolean.Parse` for "true" and "false"

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but then looked it up (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx) there is a signature for ToBoolean(string).

Comment: Yea, this is incorrect. ToBoolean(string) compares with a string for "True" or "False" and is case-insensitive. "0" or "1" will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isChecked = false;
if (request.form["mycheckbox"] != null)
{
     isChecked = (request.form["mycheckbox"]).checked;
}
```